# Program only reads the first line! C++

Tags: c++, arrays, function, arraylist, line

my program is supposed to use a .txt file as input (time in seconds 1 through 10) to calculate the distance of a falling object. The text file reads as follows:

1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10

And here is my code so far.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

//function prototype
double fallingDistance (int);

void main()
{
    ifstream inputFile;
    int time;
    double distance;

    //open the file
    inputFile.open("05.txt");
    inputFile >> time;

    {
        distance = fallingDistance (time);
        cout << time << "\t\t" << distance << endl;
    }
}
double fallingDistance (int time)
{
    double distance, gravity=9.8;
    distance = static_cast<double>(0.5 * gravity * pow(time,2));
    return distance;
}
```

And this is what my program compiles:

> `1             4.9`
>   `press any key to continue...`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I suggest looking into loops...

Comment: Your program sounds fine to me. What is the problem, exactly? It's outputting the correct value, followed by the "Press any key to continue..." stub inserted by the VS compiler in Debug configuration programs.

Comment: I want it to read past the first line of the .txt file. it should display ten lines of data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
cout << time << "\t\t" << distance << endl;
```

You first read an `int` from the input file.  Next you initialize `distance` using `time`. Then you're printing the value of `time`, two tabs, and lastly, the value of `distance`.

After this line executes `main` returns and your program exits. Why would you expect it to print anything else?

If you need to grab more values from the file then you need to use a loop, wrapping that entire process in a loop which reads from the file until it gets through the whole thing.  Something like:

```
inputFile.open("05.txt");
int time;
while(inputFile >> time) {     
    distance = fallingDistance (time);
    cout << time << "\t\t" << distance << endl;
}
```

---

On a side note, `main` is defined by the standard to have a return type of `int`, not `void`.  Omitting the arguments (`int argc` and `char *argv[]`) as you have done is fine.

Comment: Yeah I want it to print the following list, not just one line. For example. I want it to output    1   4.9  ,  2   19.6  ,  3   44.1  4   78.4, and so on up to the last value which is 10.

Comment: @JeffYoungblood: I posted an example of how to do just that. This; `inputFile >> time` reads the next value from the file and also converts to a boolean.  This means that, in the case of an error, end of file, whatever, the loop exits.  If you ever stumble upon an example which uses `while(!file.eof())` or `while(!file.fail())` or something similar you now know that it is *wrong*.  You will see this all over the place, and it is always wrong.

Comment: God I feel so stupid... haha Thank you all!